# Laravel 4 nested templates

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Dear stackoverflowers,

First of all I would like to inform you that I'm new to laravel 4, so if I'm making a fool out of myself by asking this question, then so be it..

I've set up a project and want to use templates. I have these folders/files so far:

```
--views
----home
------home.blade.php
------login.blade.php
----layouts
------master.blade.php
```

I have a get-route that makes a new view to 'home.home', which contains following code:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
{{-- zet via TAB om naar h1 met klasse 'subheader'
h1.subheader --}}
<div class="panel">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Startpagina</h1>
    </div>

@if(Auth::Guest())
    @yield('login')
@else
@endif

</div>
@stop
```

Now I want to make another template, which would function as a partial view (this could also be header, footer, ..., but for now its the login form). I thought this would've done the trick, but obviously it doesnt...

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('login')
    <p>Login form comes here</p>
@stop
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

HS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `@extends` statement in your login file, you should include it as a file in the home (and all views where you want it to appear)

Try:

```
@if(Auth::Guest())
    @include('login')
@else

@endif
```

and remove the `@extends('layouts.master')`, `@section('login')` and `@stop` in the login view itself.
All variables that exist in your home view will also be available in your login view.

In case you want the login form to act as a partial which operates with its own logic (or it needs additional data), you should consider using [view composers](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers)

Comment: I've tried this, but I get an InvalidArgumentException: View [login] not found. ?

Comment: You might consider trying `home.login` due to the directory structure.

Comment: I had tried this before. Errors are gone, but the content is not displayed.

Comment: Solved it.. the @section('login') also had to be removed. Thanks for the help! :) I edited your anwser.

Comment: Of course, the point was that you include the view instead of extending it from the layout. I am glad it is now resolved.